# Prevent User from Exploding String in PHP

Tags: php, explode

I'm in a situation where I need to explode a string which contains user input but a custom defined delimiter. I want to make sure the user cannot enter that delimiter in their input, so as not to explode the string in the wrong spot.

What is the best way to do this? Is there some type of filter I should run over the user data removing the occurrences of the delimiter? I'd think there would be a better answer than just creating a unique delimiter.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is confusing. If they can't enter that delimiter in the string how does it get in the string in the first place? And if you are putting the delimiter in on the server side then why not just reference the string position by its index instead of using a delimiter?

Comment: Not that they can't enter the delimiting character, but I'd like for it to not be interpreted as a delimiter on the server side.

Comment: If you get their string before it get concatenated with you magic delimiter, just replace all occurrences of the delimiter with an unlikely string (as seen below, e.g., '---DELIM---'). If you don't have an opportunity to do that, then the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: So what exactly is the user input and when are you inserting "the real" delimiter into it? What purpose is this for, couldn't you handle the input in a way that doesn't involve concatenating/exploding it?

Comment: the string looks like `$method:$key:$value` where each variable is userdata and the resulting array is being sent to a validation function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an ancient problem, so solve it the way it's already been solved.

In CSV files, the comma is the delimiter, yet entries can contain commas. How? Surround the entries with quotes. What if the entry contains quotes? Double up the quotes on the user input so you know they're data and not delimiters.

```
Field One,Field Two,"Field, Three","Field ""Four"""
```

PHP has functions for creating and reading CSV format with custom-defined delimiters, so you don't even have to write the code.

Comment: CSV, JSON, XML, native arrays, serialized arrays... so many options.

Comment: forgive me, but I just want to make sure I'm understanding this okay - can you provide a bit more functioning code in your example?

Comment: found this, but not available in my environment. are the memory solutions listed in the comments reasonable?

Comment: Probably. You can probably write something that will work for your situation without using the fgetcsv/fputcsv functions in just a couple lines of code as well. All you need to do is replace the delimiter or encapsulation characters if they appear in data before imploding the array to a string, and un-escaping them when exploding back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have str-getcsv in your environment, then as per the comments in your original question.

Assume your delimiter is the pipe symbol

```
$clientString = 'somestring|fobar';
$clientString = str_replace('|', '{{{somecrazydelimiter}}}', $clientString);
```

You can the later reverse the situation after exploding it and replace your temporary delimiter with original one:

```
$clientString = str_replace('{{{somecrazydelimiter}}}', '|', $clientString);
```